# Custom "business" logic using pure Django

Tags: django, forms, modelform, create-view

I am set on building a small website using django. What i am trying to do right now is using a CreateView based on a Model "Order", which one of its fields is another model "Customer".
The form itself works to create Orders, but im trying to find out how i can validate that the Customer that was selected is "enabled" (there is a status in the Customer model).

I was trying using the clean method but it doesnt even seem to be executing. I tried just raising the error on the clean, without validating anything, and still doesnt work. Any clue what might be wrong?

My Form:

```
class OrderForm(ModelForm):

    def clean_customer(self, *args, **kwargs):
        raise forms.ValidationError("This customer is banned.")


    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = '__all__'
```

Relevant Models:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    ORDER_STATUS = (('Pending Delivery', 'Pending Delivery'),
                ('Book on Customer', 'Book on Customer'),
                ('Overdue', 'Overdue'),
                ('Completed','Completed'))

    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_due = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    date_completed = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=ORDER_STATUS, null=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('orders')


class Customer(models.Model):
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, null = True, choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=25, null = True)
    email = models.EmailField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)+" - " +str(self.username)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('customers')
```

The View:

```
class OrderCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Order
    fields = '__all__'

    def form_valid(self, form):

        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: because you have set customer as null=True, django excludes the field validate automaticly.

Comment: I tried changing this and cleaning the Database but it still does not run.